# How to style LI to show quotes in a ticker

Tags: html, css

How to style `<li>` element

HTML:

```
<div id="patTest" style="width: 95%; padding: 0; margin: 0; text-align: center;">
        <ul id="patTestUL">
            <li>
                <div style="padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 98%;">
                <span style="background: #00ff00; width: 20%; text-align: right;"><img src="theImages/leftQuote.png" alt="Quote" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; padding-right: 10px;" /></span>
                <span style="color: #000000; background: #FF0000; width: 76%;">The art duo of Gilbert and George on how their work can ruffle feathers and the benefits of routine.</span>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div style="padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 98%;">
                <span style="background: #00ff00; width: 20%; text-align: right;"><img src="theImages/leftQuote.png" alt="Quote" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; padding-right: 10px;" /></span>
                <span style="color: #000000; background: #FF0000; width: 76%;">The art duo of Gilbert and George on how their work can ruffle feathers and the benefits of routine.</span>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div style="padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 98%;">
                <span style="background: #00ff00; width: 20%; text-align: right;"><img src="theImages/leftQuote.png" alt="Quote" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; padding-right: 10px;" /></span>
                <span style="color: #000000; background: #FF0000; width: 76%;">The art duo of Gilbert and George on how their work can ruffle feathers and the benefits of routine.</span>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div style="padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 98%;">
                <span style="background: #00ff00; width: 20%; text-align: right;"><img src="theImages/leftQuote.png" alt="Quote" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; padding-right: 10px;" /></span>
                <span style="color: #000000; background: #FF0000; width: 76%;">The art duo of Gilbert and George on how their work can ruffle feathers and the benefits of routine.</span>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div style="padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 98%;">
                    <span style="background: #00ff00; width: 20%; text-align: right;"><img src="theImages/leftQuote.png" alt="Quote" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; padding-right: 10px;" /></span>
                    <span style="color: #000000; background: #FF0000; width: 76%;">The art duo of Gilbert and George on how their work can ruffle feathers and the benefits of routine.</span>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div style="padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 98%;">
                    <span style="background: #00ff00; width: 20%; text-align: right;"><img src="theImages/leftQuote.png" alt="Quote" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; padding-right: 10px;" /></span>
                    <span style="color: #000000; background: #FF0000; width: 76%;">The art duo of Gilbert and George on how their work can ruffle feathers and the benefits of routine.</span>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    <style>
        #patTestUL
        {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        #patTestUL
        {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
    </style>
```

shows like this:

[image]

How can I modify the code so the green and red are separated and centered like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the span with the text in it:

```
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
```

See the top li here: http://jsfiddle.net/John_C/TL2dC/

Also, it's a good idea to avoid using all those inline styles. They'll make your code difficult to maintain.

Comment: Thank you. That solved it. I will be using CSS stylesheet. This was for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what all the markup in your example does, but when I got rid of all that, all I needed was to style the list items.

```html
<div id="patTest" style="width: 95%; padding: 0; margin: 0; text-align: center;">
    <ul id="patTestUL">
        <li>The art duo of Gilbert and George on how their work can ruffle feathers and the benefits of routine.</li>
        <li>The art duo of Gilbert and George on how their work can ruffle feathers and the benefits of routine.</li>
        <li>The art duo of Gilbert and George on how their work can ruffle feathers and the benefits of routine.</li>
        <li>The art duo of Gilbert and George on how their work can ruffle feathers and the benefits of routine.</li>
        <li>The art duo of Gilbert and George on how their work can ruffle feathers and the benefits of routine.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```css
#patTestUL li {
    list-style:none; text-align:left;
    position:relative; margin:.5em 0;
    background:red;  border:1px solid black;
}
#patTestUL li::before {
    content:'“'; position:absolute; left:-40px;
    font-size:70px; height:16px; width:34px; line-height:40px;
    background:lime; border:1px solid black;
}
```

[image]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/G6jdu/1/).

If you want an image for the bullet, you may want to check out `list-style-image`. See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/G6jdu/3/).

Comment: Thanks. Can I use an image for the quote instead of the text?

Comment: Sure, just use `list-style-image`. See [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/G6jdu/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Does something like this work?

HTML:

```
<div id="patTest">
    <ul id="patTestUL">
        <li>
            <span class="quote">
                    <div class="image"></div>
            </span>
            <span class="box"></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="quote">
                    <div class="image"></div>
            </span>
            <span class="box"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#patTest {
    width: 95%; 
    text-align: center;
}
li {
    width: 98%;
}
li > * {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.image {
    width: 30px; 
    height: 30px; 
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.quote {
    background: #00ff00; 
    width: 20%; 
    text-align: right;
}
.box {
    color: #000000; 
    background: #FF0000; 
    width: 76%;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Check here to view it: http://jsfiddle.net/5pkL5/1/

The only modifications I made to the HTML was adding in the classes I made in the new CSS, so just add that to your elements.

The key ingredient here to making it all work is the "float: left", "margin-left: 2%", and "margin-bottom: 10px". This is because it will cause the quotes and boxes to push against each other, and then the margins are there to add that gap that you wanted above.